# data returning undefined when pass variable (useQuery React Apollo)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

When I pass the value directly to the field id, I'm getting the proper return, but when I try to pass it as a variable, I'm getting data undefined, Does anyone knows how I can solve this?
My graphql File:

```
   query skuContext ($id: ID) {
    sku(identifier: {field: id, value: $id}) {
    name,
    productId,
    images {
      url,
      text
    },
    specifications {
     product {
      value
     },
    },
    product{
      name,
      refId
    },
    sellers {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

the react file calling the useQuery hook

```
import SKU_CONTEXT from "somepath/sku-context.graphql
const SomeComponent = (props) => { 
    const skucontext = useQuery (SKU_CONTEXT, { 
    variables: { id: props.id }
  })

 console.log(skucontext) // skucontext.data > undefined

}
```

But if I change the graphql file to a specific value instead of receive it from a variable,
I get the proper return from the hook. How do I solve this, please?:

```
   query skuContext ($id: ID) {
    sku(identifier: {field: id, value: 5}) {
    name,
    productId,
    images {
      url,
      text
    },
    specifications {
     product {
      value
     },
    },
    product{
      name,
      refId
    },
    sellers {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just an advice, use code gen with apollo will prevent most of these things happen in the first place, expecially with the help of type-graphql.

Comment: Have you tried console.logging the props to see if the data is being passed through?